# USB mouse doesn't work in my own build of Ubuntu

Tags: usb, mouse

I made my own build of Ubuntu 16.04 x64 with this manual (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization).

I found that USB mouse doesn't work with the build. There is no cursor and reaction to clicking (neither in install wizard nor in LiveCD mode), but the mouse lights and indicates its moving. PS/2 mouse and keyboard work with the build normally. With official image of Ubuntu 16.04 x64, both mice work normally.

How to make a build with saving ability to use USB mouse?